# Deploy App Engine Managed VM for Java to non-default network

Tags: google-app-engine, google-managed-vm

While deploying a Java application to App Engine Managed VM (using gcloud preview app...), I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.firewall-rules.create) Some requests did not succeed:
The resource 'projects/my-project-name/global/networks/default' was not found
```

Our project does not have a network named "default", rather, it has been renamed and uses subnets.

Does anyone know a way to tell gcloud preview app to use a specific network? It appears to only want one specifically named "default"

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer - I haven't actually tried this :)  You should be able to override the network name in your `app.yaml`:

```
network:
  name: <network-name>
```

Add that to `app.yaml`, and redeploy.  Hope this helps!